# I did a cutdown with js, but it has a 3 second delay to start

Tags: javascript, performance, settimeout, countdown

Within the project there is a startCount() function that starts the countdown, the countdown is done, but it is taking 3 seconds to start.

Here is the function startCount():

```
function startCount(duration) {

    countDown = setTimeout( () => {
        const minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60);
        const seconds = Math.floor(duration % 60);
        
        secondsDisplay.textContent = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
        minutesDisplay.textContent = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        
        duration--;
        
        if(duration >= 0 ) {
            startCount(duration)
        }
        else {
            resetDisplay()
            toggleButtons()
        }
        console.log(duration)

    }, 1000)
}
```

And here is the complete code:

````
const startButton = document.querySelector('#startButton')
const stopButton = document.querySelector('#stopButton')
const pomodoroButton = document.querySelector('#pomodoroButton')
const breakButton = document.querySelector('#breakButton')
const longBreakButton = document.querySelector('#longBreakButton')
const soundOnButton = document.querySelector('#soundOnButton')
const soundOffButton = document.querySelector('#soundOffButton')
const addTimeButton = document.querySelector('#addTimeButton')
const removeTimeButton = document.querySelector('#removeTimeButton')

const oneNightInTokyo = new Audio('src/music/ONE NIGHT IN ＴＯＫＹＯ (320 kbps).mp3')

const secondsDisplay = document.querySelector('#seconds')
const minutesDisplay = document.querySelector('#minutes')

const seconds = parseInt(secondsDisplay.textContent)
const minutes = parseInt(minutesDisplay.textContent)

let countDown;
let duration;

startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const seconds = parseInt(secondsDisplay.textContent)
    const minutes = parseInt(minutesDisplay.textContent)
    let duration = (minutes * 60) + seconds;

    startCount(duration)
    toggleButtons()
})
stopButton.addEventListener('click', stopCount)
pomodoroButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    minutesDisplay.textContent = 25;
    secondsDisplay.textContent = '00';

    clearTimeout(countDown)
    startButton.classList.remove('hide')
    stopButton.classList.add('hide')
})
breakButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    minutesDisplay.textContent = '05';
    secondsDisplay.textContent = '00';
    
    clearTimeout(countDown)
    startButton.classList.remove('hide')
    stopButton.classList.add('hide')
})
longBreakButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    minutesDisplay.textContent = 15;
    secondsDisplay.textContent = '00';

    clearTimeout(countDown)
    startButton.classList.remove('hide')
    stopButton.classList.add('hide')
})
soundOnButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    oneNightInTokyo.play()
    oneNightInTokyo.volume = 0.2;
    toggleSoundButtons()
})
soundOffButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    oneNightInTokyo.pause()
    toggleSoundButtons()
})
addTimeButton.addEventListener('click',() => {
    const minutes = parseInt(minutesDisplay.textContent);
    const seconds = parseInt(secondsDisplay.textContent);
    minutesDisplay.textContent = minutes + 1;
    duration = (minutes + 1) * 60 + seconds;
    clearTimeout(countDown)
    startButton.classList.remove('hide')
    stopButton.classList.add('hide')
})
removeTimeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const minutes = parseInt(minutesDisplay.textContent);
    const seconds = parseInt(secondsDisplay.textContent);
    if (minutes > 1) {
        minutesDisplay.textContent = minutes - 1;
        duration = (minutes - 1) * 60 + seconds;
    } 
    clearTimeout(countDown)
    startButton.classList.remove('hide')
    stopButton.classList.add('hide')

})



function resetDisplay() {
    minutesDisplay.textContent = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
    secondsDisplay.textContent = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
}

function stopCount() {
    clearTimeout(countDown)
    toggleButtons()
}

function startCount(duration) {

    countDown = setTimeout( () => {
        const minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60);
        const seconds = Math.floor(duration % 60);
        
        secondsDisplay.textContent = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
        minutesDisplay.textContent = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        
        duration--;
        
        if(duration >= 0 ) {
            startCount(duration)
        }
        else {
            resetDisplay()
            toggleButtons()
        }
        console.log(duration)

    }, 1000)
}

function toggleButtons(){
    startButton.classList.toggle('hide')
    stopButton.classList.toggle('hide')
}
function toggleSoundButtons() {
    soundOnButton.classList.toggle('hide')
    soundOffButton.classList.toggle('hide')
}```


I tried to refactor and reduce the number of callback functions in the code, to see if it would reduce the delay to start the countdown, but so far nothing has worked.
````

Comment: Can't reproduce - first `console.log(duration)` about 1 second after initial `startCount(duration)` is called

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use setinterval instead of settimeout
here the code i have make
function startCount(duration) {
let remainingTime = duration;

```
const updateDisplay = () => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(remainingTime / 60);
    const seconds = Math.floor(remainingTime % 60);

    secondsDisplay.textContent = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
    minutesDisplay.textContent = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;

    if (remainingTime > 0) {
        remainingTime--;
    } else {
        clearInterval(countDown);
        resetDisplay();
        toggleButtons();
    }
};

updateDisplay(); // Initial call to set the display immediately

const countDown = setInterval(updateDisplay, 1000);
```

}